# Generics vs boxing

Tags: .net, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do generic interfaces in C# prevent boxing? (.NET vs Mono performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139979/do-generic-interfaces-in-c-prevent-boxing-net-vs-mono-performance)

I have one quick question... by using generics, do I completely get rid of boxing/unboxing operations?

For example, by using a List do I still get lots of boxing/unboxing?

I've read several docs on the internet but couldn't solve this specific question...

Comment: Yes.  Avoid List<object> please.

Answer (score 8):

If a class was written correctly, then using generics will avoid all boxing and unboxing. Instead, the just-in-time compiler will generate code for each version of the class that correctly handles the value types appropriately.

Comment: +1 for explicitly mentioning value types.

Comment: -1 a class was/is never boxed or unboxed - boxing is for value types only. The advantage of generics for class objects is strong typing, not no-boxing.

Comment: @pm100 : by "each version of the class" I mean the generic class. It has a different version for each type supplied as a parameter. The JIT creates different code for each value type supplied. It also creates a single version that handles all of the reference types.

Answer (score 7):

If you use it correctly then: Yes, it will eliminate boxing.

For instance,

```
List<int> table = new List<int>();
table.Add(1);
int x = table[0];
```

does not involve any boxing/unboxing.